# Porblem suscribing to topic in plugin

Tags: ros, navigation, plugin, move-base, move-base-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im working with a navigation plugin for move_base and i want to suscribe to 2 pose topics.
The compilation shows no errors but when I launch move_base it does not suscribe, but it does the rest of tasks it is designed to do.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261469/porblem-suscribing-to-topic-in-plugin/) by [alexhn](https://answers.ros.org/users/30332/alexhn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-05-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

check the result of `rosnode info YOURNODE` , you may have a typo or a different namespace of the topic you want

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2017-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0